# How to answer a datetime with Alexa?

Tags: amazon-echo

I need my Alexa skill to answer a time to the user. Is there any good way to do this ? I'm using nodeJS. Currently I have a date like this (2017-03-17T22:45:00+0100) or a timestamp (1489790820).

How to tell Alexa to answer "ten forty five p.m." or "quarter to eleven p.m.", ... something hearing like a time, not a series of numbers ? Is there anything built-in or do I have to "translate" it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at a Node.JS library like Moment that can do timestamp formatting for you:
https://momentjs.com/

Decide on the format (specifically Calendar Time seems to be what you are looking for) you want and you can output that directly to Alexa.